# How to do addition in Montgomery form?

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

I'm trying to do ECDSA signing, and I need to compute

$$\left(k^{-1} \bmod n \cdot (m + d\cdot r) \bmod n\right) \bmod n$$

I'm able to do the inverse function and multiplication in Montgomery form, but how should I add $m$? Does the arithmetic play well if I just converted $m$ to Montgomery form? Alternatively, I could do $m + d\cdot r$ in 512-bit, but things would get quite messy and slow.

Any other fast ways to do this?

Comment: Do you need the Montgomery Residue after the computation or you will turn back to the normal residue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition in Montgomery form is modular addition.

Both operands of addition, and result, are in Montgomery form.